# ko.mapping, how listening change property of object?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

how can I get change event for next object?

```
    $(function () {
    var Data = {
        id: ko.observable(15),
        name: ko.observable('my name'),
        status: ko.observable('status')
    }

    var ClickCounterViewModel = function () {
        var me = this;
        me.Model = ko.observable(Data);

        me.change = ko.computed(function () {
            var m = me.Model();
            console.log(m.status());
        });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
});
```

I get object Data from:

```
ko.mapping(AnyInitData, {}, Data);
```

Model has all properties as observable, but If any value by changed I want know about this.
It may be do through ko.computed, but I have very much properties, and don't wont doing it.

This example output of console only 'status' if status was changed, but doing nothing if property 'name' was changed.

Sorry, for my English.

Comment: How you want to know if a property has changed? Try to check here, the section "Explicitly subscribing to observables" [KO docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) Anyway ko.mapping converts all property to observable so you don't have to declare Data first.

Comment: I know that doing ko.mapping, you are right. 
I have a object Data = {very much property}, and I wont to get change event if any propery was changed. Only it. I can make ko.computed and inside there every property of object, but it isn't elegantly.

Comment: Maybe you don't read carefully the link of my previous comment but you can use this function: `myViewModel.personName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The person's new name is " + newValue);
});`

But you have to do it for every property...

Comment: Sorry, 'subscribe' is better then nothing. Now, I have not example how 'subscribe' will work with 'ko.mapping'. But I will explore it. And will add post about results. Thinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably my solution is not the most approriate or elegant way but, if you evaluate an observable inside a computed variable it is called everytime the variable changes. For example:

```
me.change = ko.computed(function () {
        var m = me.Model();
        alert('something changed');
        m.id(),m.name(),m.status();
    });
```

If you have many properties you can loop through the Model:

```
me.change = ko.computed(function () {
        var m = me.Model();
        alert('something changed');

        for (var key in me.Model()) {
            var obj = me.Model()[key]; 
             if( ko.isObservable(obj)){
                obj();                 
             }             
        }
    });
```

Also you can consider
1. Loop recursively inside Model
2. Prevent looping many times. ( It loops everytime a variable changes. You can put a counter to do it once.)

Comment: thinks, the code work correctly. If will not found other solution, will use it.